# What Idea(s) is natural isomorphism trying to convey

Tags: category-theory

Before I proceed, I would like to first acknowledge that there are similar posts to my question, but I didn't seem to understand fully. So allow me to elaborate on my inquiry.

If I view the term "isomorphic" as the mathematical translation of:

"two structures not only look alike, but behave exactly the same way", **or** "facts are preserved in between two structures".

Then how do I view natural isomorphism, as the term currently feels 'artificial' to me. All I know is how natural isomorphism arises from natural transformation, which a morphism of Functors.

Thanks and cheers !

Comment: "Facts" is, mathematically, pretty foggy. Better: isomorphism preserves algebraic structure. Period. A natural isomorphism occurs when it can be defined without regards of some given basis, or generating set or some other algebraic feature of the algebraic structure we're talking about.

Comment: I mean, it means the same thing, except the structures that are acting exactly the same are functors. And they don't "arise from" natural transformations, they are a *kind* of natural transformation.

Comment: @DonAntonio so the idea is essentially that we can consistently choose an isomorphism for every given structure?

Comment: Natural isomorphism is just the generic notion of isomorphism applied to functors. Admittedly, that's a bit ahistorical. As the sloganized form goes: categories were invented to define functors which were invented to define natural transformations (and specifically natural isomorphisms). The whole field of category theory was founded by the motivation to study natural isomorphisms. The seminal paper was [A general theory of natural equivalences](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6) which, as the title suggests, is motivated by natural isomorphisms.

Comment: A natural isomorphism is, intuitively, when you  can define isomorphisms on a bunch of structures uniformly, i.e. in a way that "doesn't depend" on each specific structure